# UIScrollView Paging with Animation Completion Handler

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, scroll-paging

I have a UIScrollview with buttons that I use for paging right and left:

```
@IBAction func leftPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

    self.scrollView!.setContentOffset(CGPointMake(0, 0), animated: true)
}
```

I'd like to perform an action after the scrollview has finished the paging animation.  Something like:

```
@IBAction func leftPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

    self.scrollView!.setContentOffset(CGPointMake(0, 0), animated: true)

    secondFunction()
}
```

The above code doesn't work because the second function runs before the scrollview is finished animating the offset.  My initial reaction was to use a completion handler but I'm not sure how to apply one to the setContentOffset function.  I've tried:

```
func animatePaging(completion: () -> Void) {

    self.mainScrollView!.setContentOffset(CGPointMake(0, 0), animated: true)

    completion()
}
```

with the call

```
animatePaging(completion: self.secondFunction())
```

But I get the error "Cannot invoke 'animatePaging' with an argument list of type '(completion())'.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Try to remove 'completion' keyword: 'animatePaging(self.secondFunction())'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you need a completion handler for the scrolling animation itself. But `setContentOffset(_:animated:)` does not have a completion handler.

One solution would be that you animate the scrolling yourself using `UIView`'s static function `animateWithDuration(_:animations:completion:)`. That function has a completion handler that you can use:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, 0)
    }) { (finished) -> Void in
        self.secondFunction()
    }
```

Comment: is there a way to achieve this but calling the same UIScrollView delegate method? (scrollViewDidScroll for example)

Comment: I am afraid I do not understand your question. Do you want to achieve calling a function after the animated scrolling by using UIScrollView's delegate methods? Or are you asking if the delegate methods get called during the animation of the scrolling?

Comment: `scrollViewDidScroll`, for example, is not getting called when I use `UIView.animateWithDuration` instead of `setContentOffset`. Is there a way to simulate the same behavior? i.e., having `scrollViewDidScroll` called on every frame change (so I can update some UI accordingly)?

Comment: If you want to use viewDidScroll during the scroll animation then you could switch back to using setContentOffset:animated and use scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation as a sort of completion handler.

Answer (score 0):

Update from joern answer - Swift 4.2

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: { [unowned self] in
   self.scrollView.contentOffset = .zero
}) { [unowned self] _ in
   self.secondFunction()
}
```